# Load gradle plugin from sibling folder

Tags: gradle

I've started to create a Gradle plugin.  The build is finishing and producing a valid plugin jar (I think), but the implementation is skeletal.  I have a couple of unit tests, but I want to have a very simple way to "system test" the plugin.

The original plugin is in my Eclipse workspace.  I want to create a second Eclipse standalone project with a build.gradle that references the jar produced by the other project, just using a relative path to the jar in the other project's "build" folder.

My first stab at this is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs "../GradleYangPlugin/build/libs"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath files("GradleYangPlugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
    }
}

apply plugin:"com.att.opnfv.yang.gradle"
```

I then just tried "gradle tasks" to see what it said.  It fails with "Plugin with id 'com.att.opnfv.yang.gradle' not found."

You might ask whether I constructed the plugin jar correctly.  That's a valid question, but I can show that's not even relevant yet.  I ran a File IO monitor (SysInternals ProcessMonitor) while I ran the build, looking for any occurrences of "GradleYangPlugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar". The only place it looked for it was in the current directory (the root directory of the second project).  This shows that the syntax I used for my "flatDir" element isn't groked by Gradle, and it's also not complaining about it.  It just ignores it, seemingly.

Comment: Try instead using mavenLocal and the coordinate version `latest.integration`. Then use the `install` task when building the plugin. That has always worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, that basically worked. That should have been obvious to me. If you write that in an answer I'll mark it as correct.